# Python,unable to call initial arguments outside the class

Tags: python

The below python class have empty dictionary as initial arguments, after calling 
`createAccount()` outside class it successfully add data to dictionary but I can't access dictionary outside class.

What changes shall I make in the below code to access the newly created account details  ?

*Please note that my error occurs in the last line of the code *

```
class SavingsAccount():
    def __init__(self):
        self.savingsAccounts = {}
    def createAccount(self, name, initialDeposit):
        print()
        self.accountNumber = int(12345)
        self.savingsAccounts[self.accountNumber] = [name, initialDeposit]
        print("Account creation has been successful. Your account number is ", self.accountNumber)


SavingsAccount().createAccount(name = 'a',initialDeposit=4)

print(SavingsAccount().savingsAccounts[12345]) # getting error here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of `SavingsAccount` with every call. After you call to `createAccount` completes, that instance is garbage-collected, as there are no references to it stored anywhere.

```
s = SavingsAccount()

s.createAccount(name='a', initialDeposit=4)
print(s.savingsAccounts[12345])
```

(See [Taohidul Islam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61409551/1126841) for how you *should* be defining the class, though.)

Answer (score 4):

You should initialize your object using `__init__`,

```
class SavingsAccount:
    def __init__(self, name, initial_deposit):
        self.accountNumber = 12345
        self.savingsAccounts = {self.accountNumber : [name, initial_deposit] }
        print("Account creation has been successful. Your account number is ", self.accountNumber)


saving_account = SavingsAccount(name='a', initial_deposit=4)

print(saving_account.savingsAccounts)
```

Also, most of the Pythonistas prefer snake_casing while naming variables.

Answer (score 1):

The line that gives the error does this actions:

1. Calls SavingsAccount.**init**() to create the object
2. Asks for the item 12345 in the dictionary (that whas just created so it's empty)

You should structure your code in a different way. You should have a list of accounts or similar that is unique, and then insert in it the accounts you create.

Answer (score 1):

Must first initialize an instance of your SavingsAccount class

```
#initialize savings account object
s = SavingsAccount()
#call created account method
s.createAccount(name="a", initialDeposit=4)
#print the account
print(s.savingsAccounts[12345])
```

Although your datastructure is confusing, why not have one instance of a savings account object represent an individuals account?  Then you could just assign member variables for values you want to track.

```
class SavingsAccount:
    def __init__(self, name, initial_deposit):
        self.account_name = name
        self.bal = initial_deposit
    def deposit(self, val):
        self.bal += val
    def return_account(self):
        return self.__dict__
```

Now you can use it more simplistically

```
s = SavingsAccount("name", 500)
s.deposit(500)
acc = s.return_account()
print(acc)
>> {"account_name": "name", "bal": 1000}
```